# How to redirect input for customaction execommand

Tags: wix

I'm trying to setup a custom action to initialize my SQLite database using the sqlite3.exe command line tool.  In a command prompt I type the following: `c:\sqlite3.exe database.db < sqlscript.sql`

My Wix custom action falls apart in the ExeCommand attribute because I cannot seem to escape out the <.

```
<CustomAction Id="InitializeDatabase" FileKey="SQLiteEXE" ExeCommand="database.db < sqlscript.sql" Execute.../>
```

I've tried "&lt" as well.

I know I could just install an empty initiailzed database but I'm curious how to redirect inputs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have to call an EXE, I reccomend using the WiX QuietExec Custom Action pattern.    Worse case you could install a .BAT file then use the cmd /c foo.bat command to call it.   Then you wouldn't have to escape the <.

Otherwise I would search for an alternative to the EXE.  I try to stick with data driven custom actions that run in process ( say C++ or C#/DTF ).

[Quiet Execution Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm)

Comment: I've had worse luck getting CAQuiets to run.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045727/caquietexec-command-string-must-begin-with-quoted-application-name

Answer (score 1):

So, what exactly is happening when you say it falls apart? Does it compile?

Just so that we're on the same page, are you ending you XML entity with the semi-colon. You probably are, but it didn't come through in your code sample. Are you using:

```
&lt;
```

If that doesn't work, you could try putting the command into a property and using CDATA tags, such as:

```
<Property Id="MyCommand">
   <![CDATA[
      database.db < sqlscript.sql
   ]]>
</Property>
```

and using that in the ExeCommand attribute:

```
ExeCommand="[MyCommand]"
```

That might work.